# How to compile and run code and make gnuplot instruction in a single command line

Tags: c++, gnuplot

Hi I am bit ignorant about shell comand of Ubuntu. I would like to know if there is a way to construct a command that automatically compile ta c++ code and run it and for example the consequentely open gnuplot and plot the data produced by the code.
I tryed to search on internet but I could not find anything which helped me with the gnuplot part!! If you have the solution or an idea or when I can learn it because it will save all of time instead of calling the 4 line command each time . Thank you.

Comment: ok for the 1st answer is just ' g++ nome.cpp && ./a.out ' I know , I mean for the gnuplot command , I know that there is somenthing similar that I did with ROOT .

Comment: You can string commands together with `;` (to ignore failures) or `&&` (to only run next if previous succeed) - like `$ foo ; bar ; baz` or `$ foo && bar && baz` .

Comment: Why does this need to be on a single command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
g++ name.cpp && ./a.out && gnuplot -e "plot 'dati.dat' - pause -1"
```

Answer (score 1):

for example:

```
g++ -o main main.cc && ./main | gnuplot -c plot.gpl
```

and the plot script `plot.gpl` reads stdin:

```
plot '<cat -' w l
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer . So i write g++ -o main main.cc && ./main and the how I plot for example a file called "dati.dat" ? in the same line command?

Comment: @AndreaAngeletti if your program generates a data file, then you don't need to pipe the output of your executable to gnuplot. You can reference the data file in the plot script instead. So you could do `g++ -o main main.cc && ./main && gnuplot -c plot.gpl`, where `plot.gpl` (located in the same directory as `main.cc`) would contain at least something like `plot 'dati.dat'  w l`...